# My apt got messed up installing boost

Tags: ubuntu, boost, apt

On ubuntu

```
#> sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 libboost-all-dev : Depends: libboost-dev but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libboost-atomic-dev but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libboost-chrono-dev but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libboost-context-dev but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libboost-date-time-dev but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libboost-exception-dev but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libboost-filesystem-dev but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libboost-graph-dev but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libboost-graph-parallel-dev but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libboost-iostreams-dev but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libboost-locale-dev but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libboost-math-dev but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libboost-mpi-dev but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libboost-mpi-python-dev but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libboost-program-options-dev but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libboost-python-dev but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libboost-random-dev but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libboost-regex-dev but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libboost-serialization-dev but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libboost-signals-dev but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libboost-system-dev but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libboost-test-dev but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libboost-thread-dev but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libboost-timer-dev but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libboost-wave-dev but it is not going to be installed
 libboost-chrono1.54-dev : Depends: libboost1.54-dev (= 1.54.0-2ubuntu3) but it is not going to be installed
 libboost-date-time1.54-dev : Depends: libboost1.54-dev (= 1.54.0-2ubuntu3) but it is not going to be installed
 libboost-exception1.54-dev : Depends: libboost1.54-dev (= 1.54.0-2ubuntu3) but it is not going to be installed
 libboost-filesystem1.54-dev : Depends: libboost1.54-dev (= 1.54.0-2ubuntu3) but it is not going to be installed
 libboost-graph-parallel1.54-dev : Depends: libboost1.54-dev (= 1.54.0-2ubuntu3) but it is not going to be installed
 libboost-graph1.54-dev : Depends: libboost1.54-dev (= 1.54.0-2ubuntu3) but it is not going to be installed
 libboost-iostreams1.54-dev : Depends: libboost1.54-dev (= 1.54.0-2ubuntu3) but it is not going to be installed
 libboost-locale1.54-dev : Depends: libboost1.54-dev (= 1.54.0-2ubuntu3) but it is not going to be installed
 libboost-log1.54-dev : Depends: libboost1.54-dev (= 1.54.0-2ubuntu3) but it is not going to be installed
 libboost-math1.54-dev : Depends: libboost1.54-dev (= 1.54.0-2ubuntu3) but it is not going to be installed
 libboost-mpi1.54-dev : Depends: libboost1.54-dev (= 1.54.0-2ubuntu3) but it is not going to be installed
 libboost-program-options1.54-dev : Depends: libboost1.54-dev (= 1.54.0-2ubuntu3) but it is not going to be installed
 libboost-python1.54-dev : Depends: libboost1.54-dev (= 1.54.0-2ubuntu3) but it is not going to be installed
 libboost-random1.54-dev : Depends: libboost1.54-dev (= 1.54.0-2ubuntu3) but it is not going to be installed
 libboost-regex1.54-dev : Depends: libboost1.54-dev (= 1.54.0-2ubuntu3) but it is not going to be installed
 libboost-serialization1.54-dev : Depends: libboost1.54-dev (= 1.54.0-2ubuntu3) but it is not going to be installed
 libboost-signals1.54-dev : Depends: libboost1.54-dev (= 1.54.0-2ubuntu3) but it is not going to be installed
 libboost-system1.54-dev : Depends: libboost1.54-dev (= 1.54.0-2ubuntu3) but it is not going to be installed
 libboost-test1.54-dev : Depends: libboost1.54-dev (= 1.54.0-2ubuntu3) but it is not going to be installed
 libboost-thread1.54-dev : Depends: libboost1.54-dev (= 1.54.0-2ubuntu3) but it is not going to be installed
 libboost-timer1.54-dev : Depends: libboost1.54-dev (= 1.54.0-2ubuntu3) but it is not going to be installed
 libboost-wave1.54-dev : Depends: libboost1.54-dev (= 1.54.0-2ubuntu3) but it is not going to be installed
 libboost1.54-all-dev : Depends: libboost1.54-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

That last line: **Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).**

Okay.

```
#> sudo apt-get -f install

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libboost-atomic1.53.0 libboost-chrono1.53.0 libboost-context1.53.0 libboost-graph-parallel1.53.0 libboost-graph1.53.0 libboost-iostreams1.53.0 libboost-math1.53.0 libboost-mpi1.53.0 libboost-python1.53.0 libboost-random1.53.0
  libboost-serialization1.53.0 libboost-signals1.53.0 libboost-test1.53.0 libboost-timer1.53.0 libboost-tools-dev libboost-wave1.53.0 libboost1.53-tools-dev openjdk-7-jre-lib
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libboost1.54-dev
Suggested packages:
  libboost1.54-doc libboost-coroutine.54-dev libboost-log.54-dev doxygen default-jdk fop
The following NEW packages will be installed
  libboost1.54-dev
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
51 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/10.3 MB of archives.
After this operation, 101 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
(Reading database ... 253168 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking libboost1.54-dev (from .../libboost1.54-dev_1.54.0-2ubuntu3_i386.deb) ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/libboost1.54-dev_1.54.0-2ubuntu3_i386.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/boostbook/xsl/docbook-layout.xsl', which is also in package libboost1.53-tools-dev 1.53.0-6+exp3ubuntu8
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libboost1.54-dev_1.54.0-2ubuntu3_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

How do I get out of this mess? Thanks.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic. Seems to be better at the Ubuntu specific forum.

Comment: It might be easier to download Boost from its official website. Building it (if you need the libs, which are not header-only) is a matter of 2 lines.

Answer (score 9):

Some commands are redundant, but for a good measure:

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove libboost-all-dev libboost-dev libboost-doc
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libboost1.54-dev
```

Be slightly careful about `apt-get clean` - it clears the local repo of retrieved packages in `/var/cache/apt/archives`. You shouldn’t have stored anything there, nor any application, but just be aware that the cache will be gone.

Comment: That first line fails with lots of errors along the lines of `The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 libboost-chrono1.54-dev : Depends: libboost1.54-dev (= 1.54.0-2ubuntu3) but it is not going to be installed`

Comment: And did you proceed with the other lines?

Comment: Line 2 fails as described in the question, line 3 fails with lots of dependency errors.

Comment: And what happens when you persevere and get to the last line?

Comment: dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/libboost1.54-dev_1.54.0-2ubuntu3_i386.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/boostbook/xsl/docbook-layout.xsl', which is also in package libboost1.53-tools-dev 1.53.0-6+exp3ubuntu8
No apport report written because MaxReports has already been reached

Comment: It seems to me that your system is in a disarray with respect to packages. I suggest that you seek advice on cleaning it up on http://serverfault.com

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue just now.
To solve it

1. Download the libboost1.54-dev deb package from [Ubuntu packages site](http://packages.ubuntu.com/saucy/amd64/libboost1.54-dev/download)
2. Force overwrite conflicts by

   sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite libboost1.54-dev_1.54.0-2ubuntu3_amd64.deb
3. Then install packages which failed

   sudo apt-get install -f
4. Remove boost 1.53 with

   sudo apt-get autoremove

Answer (score 2):

this repo https://launchpad.net/~boost-latest/+archive/ubuntu/ppa contains all the versions of libboost and fixed it for me!

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:boost-latest/ppa
sudo apt-get update`

now you can install the version you desire, the latest at the time of writing is 1.55:

`sudo apt-get install libboost1X.55-all-dev`

Comment: this was working for my out of the box! (while all other answers did not work for me) - thanks

Comment: When I execute `sudo apt-get install libboost1X.55-all-dev`, I met E: Unable to locate package libboost1X.55-all-dev
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'libboost1X.55-all-dev'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'libboost1X.55-all-dev'.

Answer (score 1):

I initially tried mockinterface's suggestion above and persevered through but  still got the problem.

Eventually I checked the error was on the package: libboost1.54-dev_1.54.0-2ubuntu3_amd64.deb

So I ran: sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite  /var/cache/apt/archives/libboost1.54-dev_1.54.0-2ubuntu3_amd64.deb

I then ran apt-get update and apt-get upgrade and all was happy with the system again.

The apt-get upgrade is important as it sets up the various libraries again properly.

Answer (score 1):

For me, it worked installing manually the packages that "are not going to be installed" (in this order):

sudo apt-get install libboost1.46-dev
sudo apt-get install libboost-dev
sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev

The installation works fine, but I didn't test out if the package works yet.

Answer (score 0):

I tried what @mockinterface was going for but with `synaptic`. Did complete removal wherever possible of anything mentioning `boost` and notated what was being killed (strangely enough, `aptitude`, among several) to reinstall later.

Then as @Igor R. suggested in a comment, built `boost` from source.

At that point `/usr/local/lib/liboost*.so*` was full of stuff, of I believe later vintage than the Debian/Ubuntu repository.

However it appears to be a massive undertaking to remove *all* of `boost` because libreoffice, compiz, and unity depend on `libboost-date-time1.54.0`, `libboost-program-options1.46.1`, and `libboost-serialization1.46.`.

Answer (score 0):

```sh
sudo aptitude install libboost1.55-all-dev
```

This finally worked for me.

Comment: this not work to me: Couldn't find any package whose name or description matched "libboost1.55-all-dev"

Comment: which os you using? this problem only shows in ubuntu 14 which install boost 1.54

Comment: I'm using ubuntu 16.4

Comment: ubuntu 16.4 should work with normal "sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev"

Comment: yes, sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev, it works fine, however this installs the latest version, but I need to compile a program that was created with version 1.55