# libboost_system error conflicting packages

Tags: ubuntu, boost, apt

In trying to run a bin file i recieve the following error message

`error while loading shared libraries: libboost_system.so.1.55.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

I usually use Synaptic package manager for managing my packages, and it shows that libboost1.55 is installed.

[image]

I searched for my error and found [this page](https://askubuntu.com/questions/686413/how-can-i-install-boost-1-55-on-ubuntu-15-10) which mentioned that I should `sudo apt-get install libboost1.55*`

Upon running that command I get the following error:

`libboost1.55-dbg : Conflicts: libboost1.54-dbg but 1.54.0-4ubuntu3.1 is to be installed
 libboost1.55-dev : Conflicts: libboost1.54-dev but 1.54.0-4ubuntu3.1 is to be installed
 libboost1.55-doc : Conflicts: libboost1.54-doc but 1.54.0-4ubuntu3.1 is to be installed
 libboost1.55-tools-dev : Conflicts: libboost1.54-tools-dev
                          Conflicts: libboost1.54-tools-dev:i386
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.`

I have been trying for a while to fix this error by visiting [SO questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21510633/my-apt-got-messed-up-installing-boost), I am very new to Ubuntu as I have been using Mac for development until now, and am not sure how to correct this error from here.